# how to show the different titles on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the button group name, that means the different titles(section-1, section-2) when I click on  buttons. Right now it's showing the same title. 
See the [screenshot of my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzQqs.png).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="col-md-3" style="background:#e5eb8e; ">

        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <li ><h2>Section-1</h2></li>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-1</button></li><br>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-2</button></li><br>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-3</button></li><br>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-4</button></li><br>
        </ul>

        <ul style="list-style:none;">
             <li class="section"><h2>Section-2</h2></li>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-5</button></li><br>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-6</button></li><br>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-7</button></li><br>
        </ul>

        <ul style="list-style:none;">
             <li class="section"><h2>Section-3</h2></li>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-8</button></li><br>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-9</button></li><br>
            <li ><button class="my-btn" style="width:100%">Button-10</button></li><br>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="background: #c2c2f7 ;height: 800px;">

    <div class="workarea">

        <div class="work-area-header"></div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            var sectionName=$(".section").text();
            $(".my-btn").click(function(){

              $(".work-area-header").replaceWith("sectionName");

            });
        });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for something like this?

```
$(".my-btn").click(function(){
  $(".work-area-header").replaceWith($(this).closest("ul").find(".section > h2").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add class to button as per section like:

   ```
   <button class="my-btn Section-3" style="width:100%">Button-10</button>`
   ```
2. make changes in JavaScript function:

   ```
    $(function(){
       var sectionName=$(".section").text();
       $(".my-btn").click(function(){
           section = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
           alert(section);
           $(".work-area-header").text(section);
       });
    });
   ```

   [codepen link](http://codepen.io/chetantete/pen/NXWROJ)

Answer (score 0):

When you do: `$(".section").text()`. It's going to get all the element with that class name, and text will return the `text` value of the first element.

In order to get the right text, you need to find the proper element relative to the button you clicked. For this, you can use the `parent` method and then search in the children of the parent for an element with the class name `.section`.

```
$(function(){
  $(".my-btn").click(function(){
    var sectionName = $(this).parent().find(".section").text();
    $(".work-area .work-area-header").html(sectionName);
  });
});
```

Also, do not use `replaceWith` in this case as it will effectively replace one element by the other. As a result, the element you found while cliking button X will be gone the next time you click on button X.